# ImportError: No module named ' ' while Import class in the __init__.py file Python

Tags: python, import

I am new to python programming. I have create package called kitchen. I want import a class file through `__init__.py` file.

I am python version : 3.3.2

OS platform : windows

**Fridge.py**

```
class Fridge:   
    def __init__(self, items={}):
        """Optionally pass in an initial dictionary of items"""
        if type(items) != type({}):
            raise TypeError("Fridge requires a dictionary but was given %s" %
    type(items))
        self.items = items
        return

    def _Get_Items(self):
        print(self.items);

    def _Get_Added_Values(self,lst):
        values =0;
        print(len(lst));
        for index in lst:
            values += index;
        return values
    def _Get_Seperetor(self,str1,lst):
        str1=str1.join(lst);
        return str1;


    def _Get_Keys(self):
        print(self.items.keys());
```

**Courses.py** file

```
class Courses:
    def __init__(self, items=[]):
        """Optionally pass in an initial dictionary of items"""
        if type(items) != type([]):
            raise TypeError("Fridge requires a dictionary but was given %s" %
    type(items))
        self.items = items
        return

    def _Get_Items(self):
        print(self.items);

    def _Get_Seperetor(self,str1,lst):
        str1=str1.join(lst);
        return str1;


    def _Get_Keys(self):
        print(self.items.keys());
```

`__init__.py`

```
from Courses import Courses
from Fridge import Fridge
```

These are files is resided at Kitchen is the **package**

```
import Kitchen
```

While executing this command I am getting following error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "", line 1, in 
>           import Kitchen
>         File "E:\Mani\Learnings\Phython\Kitchen__init__.py", line 1, in 
>           from Courses import Courses
>       ImportError: No module named 'Courses'

Please help me how to handle this and also please let me know where I went wrong

Comment: I know you're new to Python, but a) don't check types b) don't use mutable default arguments c) use underscore_separated format for names d) no need for `return` unless you're returning a value e) no semicolons at end of lines f) consider whether you really need classes at all.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: Thanks for the valuable suggestions

Comment: @DanielRoseman > don't check types < what about using `assert isisntance(items, dict)` instead of `if type(items) != type({})`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are using Python 3. Do

```
from .Courses import Courses
from .Fridge import Fridge
```

Python 2 would look for `Courses` module in the same dir, but Python 3 looks for `Courses` module in site packages - and, obviously, it's not there.

P.S. "Phython" - sounds interesting ;)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Let me check

Comment: Also check [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and name modules in lower_case

Comment: Thank you so much! I spent hours until get to the solution (your answer)... I wonder why such details like this had to change from one version to another. T.T

Comment: @EduardoReis this was a long standing issue which was fixed in Python 3: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#rationale-for-absolute-imports

Comment: @warvariuc, I was trying to include a module from a sibling folder and I got:
SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import.
I created the __init__ and imported the modules for both folders. Would you have any guess?

Comment: @EduardoReis Sorry could not understand the issue. Anyway, you better create another question for it.

Comment: @warvariuc Thank you so much. What I don't get is how any answer or any information about Python it isn't mandatory to show usable code for Python 3 as well. If anything, Python 3 should be the default.

Comment: @BenjaminR yes, IMO Python docs suck. It would be nice to comments sections like in PHP with notable examples/remarks from users.